# Autoplay Youtube video on mobile after inserting iframe dynamically through user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, youtube-iframe-api

I am bulding a responsive webpage using embedded Youtube videos via IFrames. The IFrame is not loaded directly/upon page load but only inserted into the DOM via Javascript after the user has clicked a placeholder `<img>`.

So currently I am relying on the player event `onReady` to start the video after insertion, practically resulting in autoplay behaviour.

This works fine on desktops but not on mobile, due to autoplay restrictions, saying the event must be "initiated by a user interaction": https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Autoplay_and_scripted_playback
which the onReady event isn't, at least not directly in this case.

As a result, on mobile, I am getting the *"If playback doesn't begin shortly try restarting your device"* message and the user would have to tap the player again to start playing.

Is there any chance to work around this, maybe 'forward' this user interaction event (which I feel would be like trying to bypass that restraint). Or will I have to embed the `<iframe>` code directly?

--

Another question arising is that I feel this must have been working until some time ago, so maybe YouTube's IFrame API changed?

Comment: Late but still valide: Autoplay policies have changed a lot last years. More explanations available here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes